# Intel Ethernet not working, 20.04

Tags: networking, ethernet

Dell Latitude 3340, Wifi working but ethernet connection not. It does work on the same machine when booting into the Windows partition.

- Disabled "Fast Startup" in Windows
- Tried updating the kernel to HWE stack kernel `5.11.0-41-generic`
- Tried changing "managed" to "true" in the newtork manager .conf file and restarting the manager.

(Note: I installed Ubuntu when this SSD was in a different laptop, and after a while moved the SSD into this Dell. Everything worked smoothly other than this Ethernet issue, which may be related).

Thanks for any help!

`$ lspci -nnk | grep net -A2` is identical when plugged and when unplugged:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection I218-LM
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
Memory at f7e00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
Memory at f7e3c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 should be running either the original kernel branch (5.4.x) or the HWE stack kernel which is 5.11 now if I'm not mistaken. And either should already support that Ethernet card. If you're dual-booting then you must disable Fast Startup in Windows and shutdown. Try that before any further troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks, I am now running the HWE kernel and I disabled Fast Startup in Windows. Ethernet is still not detected though.

Comment: "Not detected" and "not working" are different situations. In the question you showed it being detected. Perhaps you should try a live session to see if it works there. If so then probably reinstalling is the best way forward (faster and better end result).